# Could not find com.github.kk121:File-Loader:1.2. while building app gives this error

Tags: android, gradle

Could not find com.github.kk121:File-Loader:1.2.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/kk121/File-Loader/1.2/File-Loader-1.2.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/kk121/File-Loader/1.2/File-Loader-1.2.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/kk121/File-Loader/1.2/File-Loader-1.2.pom
Required by:
project :app

how solve this error

Comment: Can you post your `app/build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Instead of adding maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in your project level gradle file add it in `settings.gradle`

In `settings.gradle`

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
```